# How to apply functions to a Dataframe with arrays within it, in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I hope to be clear on the questions, but let me explain me better, I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
  m = pd.DataFrame({'A': (1, 2, 3), 
                    'B': ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8])})
```

My objective is to obtain the column z which is each y-array squared plus the x-integer corresponding the position in the columns. Maybe you can get it in that way:

```
  m = pd.DataFrame({'A': (1, 2, 3), 
                    'B': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]),
                    'C': ([2, 5, 10], [18, 27, 38], [52, 67, 84])})
```

I can do it in R using this code:

```
m <- m %>% mutate(z = map2(x,y, ~map2_dbl(.x,.y, ~ (.x + .y^2))))
```

Is there something similar in Python? 
Regards

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? What does your data actually look like? Storing lists in a DataFrame is not ideal.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the question. I know that the way I stored that data is not the best, however, this is a dataframe with is composed of different discount rates for cashflows with different periods (some have 20 years, others 10 and so on). I must to stored in that way in order to deliver the NPV and have each cashflow presented. If you know a better way to store the data, I am open to suggestions. Regards

Answer (score 2):

In `pandas` , and since you have object in your column, which will make most of the method from pandas not work, we use for loop here. This method should be fast enough ~

```
m['C']=[(x + np.array(y)**2).tolist() for x , y in zip(m.A,m.B)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know about this zip module. Regards

Answer (score 2):

This could get pretty inefficient by using python lists. I'd suggest you to use `numpy` here:

```
import numpy as np

m['C'] = (np.stack(m.B.values)**2 + m.A.values[:,None]).tolist()
```

---

```
print(m)

A          B             C
0  1  [1, 2, 3]    [2, 5, 10]
1  2  [4, 5, 6]  [18, 27, 38]
2  3  [7, 8, 9]  [52, 67, 84]
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! That was pretty handy